# How to clear fragment-related status when swiping ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, contextual-action-bar

In my android application, I layout the main activity using ViewPager with Action Bar. The
PagerAdapter is FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

My first fragment contains a ListView with batch contextual actions enabled. When CAB is on the screen, I swipe to the next fragment, it is still on. Actually, it is kept in all fragments. How can I remove it when swiping?

There may be other states keeping when swiping. How can remove them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your activity implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`
2. Set the `OnPageChangeListener` of your `ViewPager` to be the activity
3. In your overridden onPageSelected(int position) method, dissmiss your CAB

Comment: I have written this code and it works. `<@Override public void onPageSelected(int position) { if(mLastPositon >= 0 && mLastPositon != position && mTabs.get(mLastPositon).fragment instanceof BaseViewPagerFragment) { ((BaseViewPagerFragment)mTabs.get(mLastPositon).fragment).clear(); } mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position); }>`  I dismiss CAB in the clear method, but how can I restore the CAB when I swipe back?

Comment: Well, you've already got the logic to dismiss the CAB when the selected page is anything either than an instance of `BaseViewPagerFragment`, correct? Put an else in your if and implement a method that returns the CAB when selected page is an instance of `BaseViewPagerFragment`

Comment: I don't know how to show CAB. I have simply tried setItemChecked method on the list view in the onCreateView callback, but it just make the item checked(CAB not showing) when I frist load my fragment.  My Code is `mTaskView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
  mTaskView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(onTaskLongClickListener);
  mTaskView.setItemChecked(0, true);`  I roughly read the setItemChecked source code `if (value && mChoiceMode == CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL && mChoiceActionMode == null) {
            mChoiceActionMode = startActionMode(mMultiChoiceModeCallback);}`

Comment: and I think the startActionMode method should be invoked. Do I miss something or something wrong ?

Comment: I have just tried to move the setItemChecked mothod to onStart callback and it works. I can't figure out the reason.

Comment: Yes, in order for the CAB to be shown, startActionMode should be called somewhere and in your case, when an item is selected in your list. You don't explicitly call startActionMode since the setItemChecked method does that for you. I would have advised you to explicitly call startActionMode in your onPageChangedListener but it seems that you have already found a method that solves your problem.